# Вывод сообщения из resource.bundle в thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Есть java код :

```
String error = "#{info.data}"; // Где info.data- сообщение из resource.bandle с переводом
model.addAttribute("error", error);
```

и есть HTML файл с атрибутом error :

```
<H3 ALIGN="center" th:text="${error}" ></H3>
```

Вопрос состоит в том, как отобразить переменную из resource.bundle (#{info.data}), что бы она автоматически переводилась.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thymeleaf автоматически разрешит статические [Messages](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#messages) и ваш HTML код выглядит просто ...

```
<H3 ALIGN="center" th:text="#{info.data}"></H3>
```

Если вы хотите динамически присвоить текст из контролера, то есть пару способов ...

1. JAVA возвращает Id ресурса

   ```
   String errorId = "info.data";
   model.addAttribute("errorId", errorId);
   ```

   HTML

   ```
   <H3 ALIGN="center" th:text="#{${errorId}}"></H3>
   ```
2. JAVA возвращает ресурс строку

   ```
   //define and initialize ...
   MessageSource messageSource;
   Locale locale;

   String error = messageSource.getMessage("info.data", null, locale);
   model.addAttribute("error", error);
   ```

   HTML

   ```
   <H3 ALIGN="center" th:text="${error}"></H3>
   ```